# Python: Memory Error when creating large array of unique values

Tags: python, arrays, timeit

I'm learning python, and I came across a problem that asks to evaluate running times on
sets of random inputs of length 10^8 using timeit. I know how to use timeit, but I'm having trouble creating the array of size 10^8. Below, I show my methods.

```
t = Timer(lambda: inversions_brute_force([4, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1]))
print 'time:' + str(t.timeit(number=1))
```

to get the array, I tried doing this:

```
import random
print random.sample(range(10**8), 10**8)
```

but I'm met with a memory error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `generator`?

Comment: How would I keep the elements unique in a generator?

Comment: How are you going to generate unique `10**8` elements from a list `[0..10**8-1]` which length's `10**8`?

Comment: If you would like to shuffle semi-randomly a list of `[0..10**8-1]` elements, you could try to randomly select a starting point `[0..10**8-1]` and randomly select a number that `GCD(10**8, that_number) == 1`. With such selected number, keep adding `that_number` to `starting_point` modulo `10**8` until you get back to your starting point. That way you will be sure you've traversed whole list, and random starting point and random offset guarantee semi-random sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your got a Memory Error because a python list contains 10**8 integers is really huge.

I did a little test with [memory_profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler). range(10**8) takes nearly 3GB memory on my laptop, so it is normal if your computer memory is less than 3GB.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
==========================================
 2                             @profile
 3    16.242 MB     0.000 MB   def foo():
 4   779.199 MB   762.957 MB       a=np.arange(10**8)
 5   779.207 MB     0.008 MB       np.random.shuffle(a)
```

You said:

> I came across a problem that asks to evaluate running times on sets of random inputs of length 10^8 using timeit.

I am just wondering what are you evaluating, your algorithm or the speed/memory usage of Python ? And why the length should be 10^8? could the length be smaller?

BTW, the memory usage can be optimized by using numpy. random.sample also should be replaced with random.shuffle when you just want the sequence to be random, latter is much more efficient in both speed and memory usage.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
 3                             @profile
 4    16.242 MB     0.000 MB   def foo():
 5   779.199 MB   762.957 MB       a=np.arange(10**8)
```